# Why is Firefox forgetting my settings?

Tags: firefox

My Firefox chrome (the menus and such) is set up like this: My the book mark items that are normally on the Bookmark bar are moved to be next to the File/Edit menus. The bookmark bar is hidden. I also have removed the search bar, since I used smart keywords.

About half the time I open a new window, or restart Firefox, the book marks are gone, and the search bar comes back next to the address bar.

I am currently running Firefox 3.5.4 on Ubuntu 9.10, but I have seen this behavior in the past on Firefox 3.0 and Windows 7, Windows XP and Ubuntu 9.04.

This is a long time problem, that I cam quite frustrated with.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check for permissions on where firefox is storing your profile?

Comment: I have not explcitly checked this, but I am pretty sure it is not the problem. The rest of the profile works (theme, extensions, home pages, most of the chrome) just these few things change back.

Comment: Have you tried creating another profile and check if it works as intended? Perhaps some files in the profile are corrupted and firefox use default options.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check / edit / delete the user.js file, see this article:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file

Answer (score 0):

As quick workaround, backup your profile with this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109/